Stop the blinking of the record enable R buttons on tracks in Logic Pro
Is there anyway to make the R-buttons ("record enable") on the tracks in Logic Pro 11.1 stop blinking and get back the old behaviour where they were just constantly lit up?
It's absolutely killing me that I have to work in slow motion and stare at the screen for several seconds to determine which tracks are armed, instead of just glancing for a split-second.
I know they stay lit during recording, but that's beside the point.

My background was in Cakewalk Sonar Studio, which was awesome until it got killed.

Sounds like you should do a feature request to Logic ;)
